# Can't compile a program.c using gcc over linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

```
gcc determinante.c
```

Is what I write in the terminal, what I get is:

```
cc1: unrecognized option `-imultiarch'
cc1: unrecognized option `-auxbase'
cc1: too many filenames. Type cc1 --help for usage info
cc1: unrecognized option `-fstack-protector'
cc1: output filename specified twice
```

I don't understand what is happening, I have commented almost all my program code, but I still having the same problem.

What is happening?

EDIT: The output of env is big but I think this two are important:

```
ARCHDIR=/usr/bin/mips-x86.linux-xgcc
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/bin/mips-x86.linux-xgcc
```

Some time ago I installed a cross compiler and added this two variables, now I suppose I have to delete them, I don't remember where are added this variables, I am looking for them.

PROBLEM SOLVED: this variables were in etc/environment, I commented them and now all is working fine.

Comment: You likely have a broken or incomplete compiler install. sudo apt-get build-essential on a debian style system, or get whatever the comparable purpose package is in your distribution.

Comment: The errors have nothing to do with your program code, they're all referring to arguments being given to the internal commands within the compiler.

Comment: @ChrisStratton My distribution is ubuntu, I tried reinstalling gcc, gcc 4.9 base and gcc 4.8 base using synaptic, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try putting a back-slash in front of gcc: `\gcc determinante.c`. You may have an alias defined in your shell and this would prevent it from being used.

Comment: What is the result of `type gcc`?

Comment: Could you give us output of following command: "gcc -dumpspecs"? I suspect that there is some problem with spec file for gcc. It is not a problem with your code, but with gcc.

Comment: Don't you have *flags* in an environment variable ? Could you show the output of `env` command ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I think you are right, this can be the problem, look my edit.

Comment: @DoxyLover back-slash doesn't work.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the result is:  gcc is /usr/bin/gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that the cross compiler has interaction with gcc compilation. You should remove the environment variable relative to cross compilation.